# Postgres удалить таблицы с определенным префиксом

Tags: postgresql

есть тригер партицирования, создающий от мастер таблицы партиции вида

master_2015-01

master_2015-02

каким образом при создании партиции я могу удалить партиции старше определенного интервала (предположим 12 месяцев)

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно прибегнуть к использованию PostgreSQL Partition Manager Extension.

Этот экстеншен опционально умеет освобождать ненужные дочерние партиции.

[Документация](http://pgxn.org/dist/pg_partman/doc/pg_partman.html)

[Исходник на гитхабе](https://github.com/keithf4/pg_partman)